# "Mirage of factors"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-origin

Today I came across the phrase "mirage of factors", used in the same way one would say "variety of factors". I thought this had to be a mistake, but a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mirage%20of%20factors%22) shows that this is indeed a niche phrase, returning ~23,000 results.

My dictionary doesn't have a definition for 'mirage' that fits this usage, so I have to guess this is a minor turn of phrase. Has anyone else come across this phrase, and does anyone know its history?

Comment: There are only 41 results in Google. Don't trust their estimates.

Comment: Methinks perhaps an eggcorn for the phrase *myriad of factors*?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Either that, or "barrage of factors" or a co-mingling of the two.

Answer (score 2):

In perhaps a very specific context, mirage of factors might refer to conflicting factors or factors created a mirage together. For example, "it was the mirage of factors that had caused Napoleon underestimate Russia's winter which ultimately led to his downfall."(It's a bit weird but native english speakers will know what you mean). It's definitely not a set phrase you will find in the dictionary. However, I agree with High Performance Mark that it is most likely a typo for myriad.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.